# Challenges & Strange Experiences while Working with System V Semaphores

Tags: ipc, semaphore, fifo, atomic

**System:**

Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-57-generic-pae i686 GNU/Linux

**Problem:**

I wanted to make use of semaphore to implement process atomicity

Below program simply writes some data to FIFO while some other processes also try to write to the same FIFO but the process below which gets the semaphore first has to complete its write up and release the key for others

*header.h*

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
//#include<sys/ipc.h>
//#include<sys/sem.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define RES_FIFO 1234
#include<linux/sem.h>
typedef struct
{
pid_t   pid;
int     op1;
int     op2;
char    oper;
}MATH;
int result;
int ret;
```

*Process:*

```c
#include"header.h"
int
main(void)
{
 MATH request;
 int fd,KK;
 if(access("TEMP",F_OK)== -1)
    mkfifo("TEMP",0666);
 fd=open("TEMP",O_WRONLY,0666);
 int i=0;
 union semun a;
 struct sembuf sops[2]={{0,-1,SEM_UNDO},{0,1,SEM_UNDO}};
 //1.Semaphore Creation
 KK=semget(RES_FIFO,1,IPC_CREAT);//semaphore set having one semaphore is created and kernel key will be returned
 if(KK==-1)
 {
 perror("Semget Error in P1\n");
 exit(1);
 }
 //2.Semaphore Control
 a.val=1;
 ret= semctl(KK,0,a);
 if(ret==-1)
 {
  perror("SemCtl Error in P1\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 //3.Semaphore Operations
 ret=semop(KK,&sops[0],1);
 if(ret==-1)
 {
  perror("Semop Error in decrementing at P1\n");
  exit(1);
 }


 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
  request.op1=i;
  request.op2=i;
  request.oper='+';
  request.pid=getpid();
  write(fd,&request,sizeof(request));
 // sleep(1);
 }

 ret=semop(KK,&sops[1],2);
 if(ret==-1)
 {
  perror("Semop Error in decrementing at P1\n");
  exit(1);
 }
return 1;
}
```

but the problem is after semaphore operation `semop`, I am stuck up and the process is idle doing nothing and goes to sleep state. So is there anything wrong with my code ?

**LATEST EDIT 1**:

with concerned suggestions i have updated the code line

```c
ret= semctl(KK,0,SETVAL,a);//command updated as SETVAL
```

and also uncommented the line

```c
sleep(1);
```

so my process1,process2,process3 has got same code,here i forgot mention the reader code which reads from fifo and prints on console

so I run the script like this on console

```c
./reader&
./p1&
./p2&
./p3&
```

*reader.c*

```c
#include"header.h"
void
main(void)
{
 MATH request;
 int fd;
 int ret;
 int KK;
 if(access("TEMP",F_OK)== -1)
         mkfifo("TEMP",0666);
 fd=open("TEMP",O_RDONLY,0666);
sleep(3);
printf("Server Read Started\n");
 while(1)
 {
 if( (ret=read(fd,&request,sizeof(request))) == -1)
 {
  perror("Read in Server Failed\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 else if(ret==0)
  continue;
 printf("Read from PID : %d about %d %c %d \n",request.pid,request.op1,request.oper,request.op2);

 }
printf("Read Complete\n");
}
```

*According to my objective I want the output to be like this*

```c
Server Read Started
Read from PID : 3673 about 0 + 0 
Read from PID : 3675 about 1 + 1 
Read from PID : 3674 about 2 + 2 
Read from PID : 3673 about 0 - 0 
Read from PID : 3675 about 1 - 1 
Read from PID : 3674 about 2 - 2 
Read from PID : 3673 about 0 * 0 
Read from PID : 3675 about 1 * 1 
Read from PID : 3674 about 2 * 2
```

*but the actual observed output is like this*

```c
Server Read Started
Read from PID : 3673 about 0 + 0 
Read from PID : 3675 about 0 * 0 
Read from PID : 3674 about 0 - 0 
Read from PID : 3673 about 1 + 1 
Read from PID : 3675 about 1 * 1 
Read from PID : 3674 about 1 - 1 
Read from PID : 3673 about 2 + 2 
Read from PID : 3675 about 2 * 2 
Read from PID : 3674 about 2 - 2
```

I think I am successful in explaining my problem clearly. any further edit is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bug lies here in the code

```
//2.Semaphore Control
 a.val=1;
 ret= semctl(KK,0,a);
 if(ret==-1)
 {
  perror("SemCtl Error in P1\n");
  exit(1);
 }
```

where I have placed it in all three processes where they were replicas to each other , when the process2 containing same code started executing the semaphore which is decremented by process1 already is again re-initialized which has broke the atomicity of the 3 processes

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do 3 corrections for code to run:

1) You might not need this as you probably have the process that reads the queue. But as I had only your "process.c" I needed to adjust this:

fd=open("TEMP",O_WRONLY,0666); -> fd=open("TEMP", O_WRONLY **| O_NONBLOCK**, 0666);

2) This line seems to be with error and needs adjustment. To set semaphore to initial value you would need to set it with SETVAL:

ret= semctl(KK,0,a); -> ret= semctl(KK, 0, **SETVAL,** a);

3) This line seems to be with error. Last parameter is how many operations are to grab. It has to be 1:

ret=semop(KK,&sops[1],2); -> ret=semop(KK,&sops[1],**1**);